# How can I access the key of a map without knowing the type of the values?

Tags: go, types, casting

If I have a map in an interface variable and want to access a key, but do not know what type the values of the map will be, how can I access that key?

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/R4trOpx06re) is an example on go playground

To solve my problem I need to figure out how to make the main function run without errors.

Comment: Do you have a limited set of map types you're using? Then just type switch on those, otherwise you're going to have to use reflection,

Comment: No, my use case is reading json schema $ref paths, so the map values could be anything, but the keys will always be strings.

Comment: @JimB How would you use reflection to solve this problem?

Comment: If the application is reading a value decoded to an `interface{}` by the [json](http://godoc.org/encoding/json) package, then the maps are all of type `map[string]interface{}` and the code in the question will work as is.

Comment: If you expect map keys to be of any type, why is your `key string`? At the moment you can only handle `string` map keys.

Comment: @MichaelHampton sorry if my wording was unclear.  I expect the keys to always be strings, but the values to be of an arbitrary type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package to operate on arbitrary map types:

```
func GetMapKey(reference interface{}, key string) (interface{}, error) {
    m := reflect.ValueOf(reference)
    if m.Kind() != reflect.Map {
        return nil, errors.New("not a map")
    }
    v := m.MapIndex(reflect.ValueOf(key))
    if !v.IsValid() {
        return nil, errors.New("The " + key + " key was not present in the map")
    }
    return v.Interface(), nil
}
```